# Firebase Auth not working on emulator: class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-emulator, firebase-authentication

Im getting a "registration error" when I run my code and my online firebase users data is not getting updated. I checked my google play services version and updated gradle to compile with that version as I thought a later version would not work on my emulator, on my firebase project I have enabled "email/password" but my users database is not getting updated and I  am throwing the "registration error" exception in my code, my password I am using is 10 characters long and contains one uppercase, some numbers and a hash just to be sure. Why is my database not getting updated, I suspected the google play services version but have downgraded this to the version my emulator is running and suspected my password but am using a more complex one but am still throwing a registration exception. I have added internet permissions on my manifest as I thought that could be a problem as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:hint="Enter email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:hint="Enter password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSignup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Signup" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonSignup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });
    }


    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle (Module App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat log:

```
09-25 12:00:18.324 14451-14613/com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-25 12:00:18.332 14451-14613/com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-25 12:00:28.457 14451-14613/com.swaziprocurement.mobileappie W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: @Rohan Stark I am getting a "registration error" exception which is part of my code if the user registration fails, no android specific errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally sorted it out, it was that I required to update my system images on my API build tools and update my system images on my emulator, that got it working